# How to delete a row in SQL Server via Identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

What's the proper syntax for a row delete via an identity column? 
The query:

```
    "DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [column 'count'] = 1"
```

works. While the same query where the identity column is 'index' fails.

```
    "DELETE FROM [table] WHERE index = 1"
```

I'm trying to delete the last inserted row with IDENT_CURRENT([table]).

Comment: I'm trying to delete the last inserted row with IDENT_CURRENT([table])" doesn't sound like a promising idea. In what context do you need this?

Comment: I recognize the pitfalls of IDENT_CURRENT, but it looks like server CE doesn't support it anyways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index is a reserved word. You have to escape it with square brackets.

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [index] = 1
```

And be sure to give a special ["thanks"](http://www.gifbin.com/bin/072011/1310121691_game_of_thrones_tyrion_lannister_slaps_prince_joffrey.gif) to whoever designed the schema with that column name in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [index] = 1
```

as **[index is a reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)** in Sql Server.